# What does the 'hooks' function do in the python requests library?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests

def func(get_requests, *a, **b):
    print(get_requests.status_code)
    print(get_requests.text)
    
hooks = {'response':func}    
get_requests = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get', hooks=hooks)
```

What is 'hooks' in the python requests library ?

Comment: what does it do ?

Comment: is it a beneficial function or useless ? are there any other ways to do the same ?

Comment: It looks like there is only 1 hook implemented for requests - you can change the response object before all of the processing is done. There isn't a lot of documentation, but you could read through sessions.py to see the callout. You could make the remaining request code do something different by changing the value of the response.

Comment: but is it useless ? what is the benefit of it ? i can do the same without using hooks and should i use it or avoid using it what do you think ?

Comment: Like I said, you'll need to look a session.py to see if its useful for you. Search for `dispatch_hook`. Maybe you want to change cookies or history. Maybe you want to make some change to the response before other existing code gets to it. You could raise an exception if you want to. Is it useful? I don't know. Would it be nice for all non-200 response codes to raise an error? Could be cool.

Comment: See https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#event-hooks